# dynamic sizing and positioning of iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, positioning, resize

I am quite new with web design and scripting. I am trying to build a site with a banner frame at the top, menu on the left, and the main content in the large lower right section. I want the banner to size dynamically with the browser size. I accomplished this on IE8, but it would not view correctly on IE9, plus I wanted a background image that crossed frame borders I am currently trying iframes, but cannot make them fill the browser window. Occasionally, I can make the iframes change size and/or position dynamically, but its not reliable. I have tried various position types as well as wrapping the iframes in  and attempting to resize and position those as well. This is the most successful code I have, excuse any redundant, unreferenced, and commented code as it is leftovers of failed attempts.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Mountain Girl Gallery</title>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
<!--
#layer1 { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 95px; visibility: visible}
--!>
<!--
#layer2 { position: absolute; top: 95px; left: 500px; width: 100px; height: 505px; visibility: visible}
--!>
<!--
#layer3 { position: absolute; top: 95px; left: 100px; width: 900px; height: 505px; visibility: visible}
--!>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function frameResize(){
var winW;
var winH;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
document.documentElement &&
document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
winW = window.innerWidth;
winH = window.innerHeight;
}

var bframe=document.getElementById('bannerframe');
//var menuframe=document.getElementById('menu');
var mframe=document.getElementById('main');

//var f1=document.getElementById('bannerframe');
//var f2=document.getElementById('menu');
//var f3=document.getElementById('main');

bframe.style.width=winW;
bframe.style.height=winH*.2;
//menuframe.style.width=winW*.15;
//menuframe.style.height=winH*.8;
//menuframe.style.top=(winH*.2)+"px";
mframe.style.width=winW*.85;
mframe.style.height=winH*.8;
mframe.style.top=(winH*.2)+"px";
mframe.style.left=(winW*.15)+"px";

//f1.style.width=bframe.style.width;
//f1.style.height=bframe.style.height;
//menuframe.style.width=winW*.15;
//menuframe.style.height=winH*.8;
//f2.style.top=menuframe.style.top;
//f3.style.width=mframe.style.width;
//f3.style.height=mframe.style.height;
//f3.style.top=mframe.style.top;
//f3.style.left=mframe.style.left;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setSize(){
frameResize();
if(window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onresize",frameResize);
else if(window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("resize",frameResize,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body
style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: url(mountain%20girl%20background.JPG); background-attachment: fixed; background-position: 50%; height: 657px;"
onresize="frameResize()">
<div align="center">
<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 200px;"
src="banner.html" name="bannerframe" id="bannerframe" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>

<iframe style="position: relative; top: 200px; left: 0px;"
src="menu.html" name="menu" id="menu" allowtransparency="true"
frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe style="position: relative; top: 200px; left: 150px; width: 850px; height: 505px;"
src="home.html" name="main" id="main" allowtransparency="true" onload="setSize()" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I am open to any other suggestions, but I do not want to use server side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this days is not recommended use an iframe (frame: NO way!)
So i few years ago i make [an example](http://www.cereal.cl/sandbox/Load-content-w-ajax/) of how to load content without refreshing using ajax. This way you could have more control over your CSS and later mix it with other codes.

Cheers.

PS: If you could set a link to check your work, i'll be great!.

Comment: I do not have a server to host it yet. I am trying to make it usable first.

Comment: Hi again mate, well you dont need a server for that, i see you using HTML or al at least try my code. Keep in mind if you try an iframe you must add the css style or Js file's in each page, every time. Cheers.

Comment: I like the implementation and the way my page looks using your code, but I haven't gotten to fully test it yet as xmlhttprequest.open is blocked on local files, at least in IE and chrome.